# What advantages does the Seagate 8TB ST8000AS0002 have over the ST8000NM0105?

Tags: hard-drive

I looked up both on desktech.com:

1. [ST8000AS0002](https://www.disctech.com/Seagate-ST8000AS0002-8000GB-SATA-Hard-Drive)
2. [ST8000NM0105](https://www.disctech.com/Seagate-ST8000NM0105-8TB-SATA-Hard-Drive)

The price may change over time, but they currently appear to be basically identical.

The only metric that could be better is the power consumption, but it's a tiny amount in absolute terms (7.5W vs "<10").

- Cache MB: 128 vs 256
- MTBF: 800K vs 2M
- TB/Year: 180 vs 550
- Nonrecoverable Read Errors per Bits Read: 1 per 10e14 vs 1 sector per 10E15

What's the advantage of the "Archive" drive if it has a worse Nonrecoverable Read Errors per Bits Read and a worse MTBF rating?

Comment: Just a note, I always buy disks with 5-year warranties when I'm buying high capacity storage. I would also avoid SMR if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are spec sheet PDFs from Seagate:

- [ST8000AS0002 - Seagate Archive HDD](https://www.seagate.com/files/www-content/product-content/hdd-fam/seagate-archive-hdd/en-us/docs/archive-hdd-dS1834-3-1411us.pdf)
- [ST8000NM0105 - Seagate Exos 7E8](https://www.seagate.com/www-content/datasheets/pdfs/exos-7-e8-data-sheet-DS1957-1-1709-GB-en_GB.pdf)

Exos is a clear winner IMO. There are more important differences than you have listed:

- Archive HDD uses the SMR technology (vs CMR in Exos), which makes it cheaper to manufacture but significantly decreases performance under certain workloads.
- Archive has shorter warranty: 3 years vs. Exos with 5 years.
- Max R/W speeds: 190 MB/s vs. 250 MB/s
- I can't see rotational speed specified anywhere in the Archive HDD datasheet - it could be 5400 rpm vs. 7200 rpm of Exos

Archive HDD wins if you want to use it at near-freezing temperatures: Exos's specified min. temp is 5°.

Comment: Archive HDD RPM is listed as 5900 on Amazon.